# How can you update a tag synonym description?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process, tag-disambiguation

The `map` tag is a synonym of `dictionary`.

This means `map` will be swapped for `dictionary` automatically. The problem is that the description displayed for the `map` tag is currently:

> a data structure relating keys to values, or a higher order function that applies a function to a list. For questions about [...]

This is problematic because it has 2 different definitions. The first *does* correspond to `dictionary`, but the second does not. Regardless of which version of `map` you intended, `dictionary` will be added. This is confusing and leads to mis-tags.

Clearly, the description of `map` needs to be modified. How can this be done? I hope this just needs to be brought to the attention who has sufficient permissions.

Comment: Perhaps a trusted user could [edit it](http://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/7715) or you could suggest an edit.

Comment: We may edit the description, but what about already existing questions tagged with `dictionary` that are only related to the second description of `map` such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852801/map-over-list-except-for-last-list-element)?

Comment: @DanielCook Thanks, I actually did try to find that and was unable. That would qualify as an answer...

Comment: @JonSurrell It was a bit tricky...

Comment: @Holt this is a pain point with synonyms I suspect has been dealt with elsewhere, although I don't have links right now.

Comment: @DanielCook Could you share the method you used to find that link? I'd like to have an acceptable answer here.

Comment: @JonSurrell Honestly, the link I shared doesn't even seem to work anymore. >.>

Comment: @JonSurrell: I wish I shared your optimism about tag synonym pain points (or even just *tag* pain points) assuredly being dealt with somehow.

Comment: @NathanTuggy "dealt with" as in "discussed in a meta question", *not* as in "solved". Perhaps a poor choice of wording on my part.

Comment: @JonSurrell: Well, fair enough. I guess that would be more "delved into" or "explored".